# Where did the Wikipedia page for IOTA go?

Tags: iota-network

I can't find the Wikipedia page for IOTA. I thought there used to be one. What happened to it? Did it get deleted? Why? Is there a place where more information on this can be found?

Comment: Here is another source I found that may shed some light on this decision. https://web.archive.org/web/20180815014108/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draft_talk:IOTA_(cryptocurrency)

Answer (score 5):

Speaking of English Wikipeda, the [deletion discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Articles_for_deletion/IOTA_(technology)) is available here.

The [IOTA page in German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOTA_(Kryptow%C3%A4hrung)) has not been deleted so far.

I did not check Wikipedias in other languages; however, the Interwiki links from the German version can be a start to find some of them.

Comment: Thanks. That 'deletion discussion' is very educational and helps me understand Wikipedia too!

Answer (score 4):

The IOTA page on Wikipedia was deleted because it [wasn't a great Wikipedia article](http://web.archive.org/web/20171213044129/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOTA_(technology)). It was poorly sourced, contained much information that wasn't in the sources given... They just decided to rewrite it from scratch because the *article* was so terrible. The only arguments [in favour of keeping it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Articles_for_deletion/IOTA_(technology)) seem to be about IOTA's notability. And IOTA *is* notable enough to have a Wikipedia article... just not *that* article.

The article has been deleted, but **that doesn't mean that Wikipedia has no intention of there being an article about IOTA**. <del>[Here's the latest draft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draft:IOTA_(technology)) of the new article... which isn't much better to be honest. Why can't people just get together and write a decent Wikipedia article about IOTA?!</del> This draft, being practically identical to the original, has been deleted. We'll have to wait a bit for an IOTA article.

Comment: It has also been nominated for deletion along with all the other language versions here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Miscellany_for_deletion/User:TheAbascus/sandbox

Answer (score 2):

More info here. This note seems to me to be the summary comment of why the page was "SALTed" (official term, not sure what that actually means) by user Jytdog:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draft_talk:IOTA_(cryptocurrency)

[image]

Comment: Here is a good explanation how Wikipedia works (use browser translator if you don't read Russian) - https://yadocent.livejournal.com/238195.html

Comment: Looks like [WP:SALT](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia:SALT&redirect=no) means "Creation protection".